# Databinding ObservableDictionary to DataGrid not working

Tags: wpf, dictionary, data-binding, observable

*I'm using a class ObservableDictionary to try and display Dictionary items in a datagrid that will be observable. I am simply try to databind the object but the grid is coming up blank.

I added the datacontext but still get no data displayed. I see postings for the ObservableCollections but no samples for ObservableDictionary.

Here is xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="725">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name ="testGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="21,22,370,50" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
           <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Name" Width="220" Binding="{Binding Keys}" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableDictionary<string, string> _categories = new ObservableDictionary<string, string>();
        public MainWindow()
        {

            DataContext = this;

            InitializeComponent();

            _categories.Add("Island", "IS");
            _categories.Add("Land", "LD");
            _categories.Add("Sea", "SE");
        }

        public ObservableDictionary<string, string> Categories
        {
            get
            {
                return _categories;
            }
        }

}
```

And finally here is the ObservableDictionary.cs:

```
    using System.Linq;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.Specialized;

    namespace System.Collections.ObjectModel
    {
        public class ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private const string CountString = "Count";
            private const string IndexerName = "Item[]";
            private const string KeysName = "Keys";
            private const string ValuesName = "Values";

            private IDictionary<TKey, TValue> _Dictionary;
            protected IDictionary<TKey, TValue> Dictionary
            {
                get { return _Dictionary; }
            }

            #region Constructors
            public ObservableDictionary()
            {
                _Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
            }
            public ObservableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
            {
                _Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary);
            }
            public ObservableDictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
            {
                _Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(comparer);
            }
            public ObservableDictionary(int capacity)
            {
                _Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(capacity);
            }
            public ObservableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
            {
                _Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary, comparer);
            }
            public ObservableDictionary(int capacity, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
            {
                _Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(capacity, comparer);
            }
            #endregion

            #region IDictionary<TKey,TValue> Members

            public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
            {
                Insert(key, value, true);
            }

            public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
            {
                return Dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
            }

            public ICollection<TKey> Keys
            {
                get { return Dictionary.Keys; }
            }

            public bool Remove(TKey key)
            {
                if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

                TValue value;
                Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
                var removed = Dictionary.Remove(key);
                if (removed)
                    //OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
                    OnCollectionChanged();

                return removed;
            }


            public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
            {
                return Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
            }


            public ICollection<TValue> Values
            {
                get { return Dictionary.Values; }
            }


            public TValue this[TKey key]
            {
                get
                {
                    return Dictionary[key];
                }
                set
                {
                    Insert(key, value, false);
                }
            }


            #endregion


            #region ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members


            public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
            {
                Insert(item.Key, item.Value, true);
            }


            public void Clear()
            {
                if (Dictionary.Count > 0)
                {
                    Dictionary.Clear();
                    OnCollectionChanged();
                }
            }


            public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
            {
                return Dictionary.Contains(item);
            }


            public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
            {
                Dictionary.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
            }


            public int Count
            {
                get { return Dictionary.Count; }
            }


            public bool IsReadOnly
            {
                get { return Dictionary.IsReadOnly; }
            }


            public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
            {
                return Remove(item.Key);
            }


            #endregion


            #region IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>> Members


            public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
            {
                return Dictionary.GetEnumerator();
            }


            #endregion


            #region IEnumerable Members


            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return ((IEnumerable)Dictionary).GetEnumerator();
            }


            #endregion


            #region INotifyCollectionChanged Members


            public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;


            #endregion


            #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members


            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


            #endregion


            public void AddRange(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> items)
            {
                if (items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("items");


                if (items.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (Dictionary.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (items.Keys.Any((k) => Dictionary.ContainsKey(k)))
                            throw new ArgumentException("An item with the same key has already been added.");
                        else
                            foreach (var item in items) Dictionary.Add(item);
                    }
                    else
                        _Dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(items);


                    OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, items.ToArray());
                }
            }


            private void Insert(TKey key, TValue value, bool add)
            {
                if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");


                TValue item;
                if (Dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out item))
                {
                    if (add) throw new ArgumentException("An item with the same key has already been added.");
                    if (Equals(item, value)) return;
                    Dictionary[key] = value;


                    OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value), new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, item));
                }
                else
                {
                    Dictionary[key] = value;

                    OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
                }
            }


            private void OnPropertyChanged()
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(CountString);
                OnPropertyChanged(IndexerName);
                OnPropertyChanged(KeysName);
                OnPropertyChanged(ValuesName);
            }


            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }


            private void OnCollectionChanged()
            {
                OnPropertyChanged();
                if (CollectionChanged != null) CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
            }


            private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> changedItem)
            {
                OnPropertyChanged();
                if (CollectionChanged != null) CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, changedItem));
            }


            private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> newItem, KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> oldItem)
            {
                OnPropertyChanged();
                if (CollectionChanged != null) CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, newItem, oldItem));
            }


            private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, IList newItems)
            {
                OnPropertyChanged();
                if (CollectionChanged != null) CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, newItems));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, set DataContext after InitializeComponent(), not before, though that's not an issue here. And it's a better ideal to put ObservableDicitonary in a namespace of your own, don't pretend it's a framework class. That's not a bug per se, but it's better for that to be clear when you come back to the code a year from now.

Comment: I moved DataContext but I still do not see any data in grid. Can you show me how you would display the Keys or Values in the xaml please?

Comment: I do not see any rows in the grid.

Comment: Your binding to the collection itself is fine: You see three rows in the grid for three items in the collection. Here's the problem: `Dictionary<string, string>` enumerates as a series of `KeyValuePair<string, string>`. That object has two properties: `Key` and `Value`, both readonly. No `Keys` property. So your columns must bind to `Key` and `Value`, respectively: `Binding="{Binding Key}"` on the key column. And make the columns both IsReadOnly="True", or just put that on the DataGrid itself: If the user edits a cell, it'll throw an exception otherwise, because the properties are read-only.

Comment: Please post the code you're actually running. The code in your question shows three rows in the grid. That's the same whether DataContext is assigned before or after InitializeComponent().

Comment: I had to change Binding="{Binding Keys}" to Binding="{Binding Key}"

Comment: See, I told you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enumerate a `Dictionary<string, string>`, you get an enumeration of `KeyValuePair<String, String>`. That's right there in your ObservableDictionary class:

```
public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
{
    return Dictionary.GetEnumerator();
}
```

So you're binding DataGrid.ItemsSource to Categories:

```
    ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
```

The DataGrid says "here's an IEnumerable of some random thing. Let's enumerate it and use one item for each row".

Therefore, your grid row items are `KeyValuePair<String, String>`. That has two readonly properties: `Key` and `Value`. You're binding to `Keys` in your column: `Binding="{Binding Keys}"`. No such property. When a binding fails, or appears to fail, check out the Output pane in Visual Studio at runtime.

Here's the error you were getting in the Output pane:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Keys' property not found on 'object' ''KeyValuePair`2' (HashCode=-1894483822)'. BindingExpression:Path=Keys; DataItem='KeyValuePair`2' (HashCode=-1894483822); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

It's telling you that it's trying to find `Keys` on `KeyValuePair`, with no success. It's simplicity itself for you to go look at `KeyValuePair`, find out what it does have, and bind to that instead.

Finally: If the user double clicks on a cell, the DataGrid will try to edit the cell. But `Key` and `Value` are read only, so it'll throw an exception. I'm making your grid readonly to prevent that from happening. I also cleaned up the element style, to save on copying and pasting with multiple columns.

```
<DataGrid 
    Name="testGrid" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" 
    Margin="21,22,370,50" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    IsReadOnly="True"
    >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TextElementStyle">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Name" 
            Width="220" 
            Binding="{Binding Key}" 
            ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextElementStyle}" 
            />
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Value" 
            Width="220" 
            Binding="{Binding Value}" 
            ElementStyle="{StaticResource TextElementStyle}" 
            />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Note that if you replace _categories with a new instance of ObservableDictionary, the UI will never know about it. It'll keep the old dictionary, because you are not raising any change notification when the value of `Categories` changes. That's fine if you don't need to, but be aware of it. A better way to code that would be this, which prevents that mistake from being made:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = this;

        Categories.Add("Island", "IS");
        Categories.Add("Land", "LD");
        Categories.Add("Sea", "SE");
    }

    public ObservableDictionary<string, string> Categories { get; }
        = new ObservableDictionary<string, string>();
}
```

You're going to run into problems using margins for layout. It's much better to use Grid columns, StackPanels, etc. and use margins only for defining *relative* spacing between elements in a Grid or StackPanel. It becomes relatively simple to create dynamically resizable UIs, and to adjust the layout: If you want to make something wider, just set a Width on it and the rest of the layout will adjust, because it's relative instead of fixed.